# Elasticsearch Tire on rails, return all males in age range but it returns the woman too

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

**Using elasticsearch and Tire im trying to search a few profile records.**

Try to get results where gender = male and age_from = 18, age_to = 30. Currently with this setup it returns everyone that is inside this age range even woman. How Can i make it behave
to only return the males in this age range?

```
if params['people']
      tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 50, :default_operator => 'AND', :use_dis_max => true) do
        query do
          boolean do
            should { range :age, {gte: params['people'][:age_from], lte: params['people'][:age_to]} }

            should { string 'gender:male' } if params['people'][:gender] == "male"
            should { string 'gender:female' } if params['people'][:gender] == "female"

          end
        end
        to_curl
      end
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use must instead of should.
It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't program is ruby, but...

```
:default_operator => 'OR'
```

Try changing 'OR' to 'AND'

**EDIT** Ok round 2, this is fun...

Seems to me like this is wrong

```
should { string 'gender:male' } if params['people'][:gender] == "male"
should { string 'gender:female' } if params['people'][:gender] == "female"
```

Just by looking at the :age one above it, wouldn't this work better...

```
should { string :gender, {eq: params['people'][:gender]} }
```

But again, I don't program in ruby...

Comment: typo but that still returns everything

Comment: @Rubytastic - I updated the answer, those conditional should's after the range seem fishy to me.